# What's the best way to diff blocks of text between two files?

Tags: bash, diff

What flags for diff or other tools could I use to compare two files for differences in blocks of text. EX:

file1

```
record {
data1
data2
}
```

file2

```
record {
data1
data2
}

record {
data3
data4
}
```

and the output would be like

```
record {
data3
data4
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff` command as

```
diff -a --suppress-common-lines file2 file1
```

(Or) Use `grep` as

```
grep -Fxvf file1 file2
```

With the following flags,

```
-F, --fixed-strings
              Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.    
-x, --line-regexp
              Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
-v, --invert-match
              Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
-f FILE, --file=FILE
              Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

Another way using `awk`

```
awk 'NR == FNR {unique[$0]++; next} !($0 in unique)' file1 file2
```

Comment: `grep -Fxvf` look slike what I want but when I run it I get no output.

Comment: Worked fine for me. The diff command didn't work too?

Comment: @red_eagle : try the solution in awk in the latest update, which should work for you.

Comment: The 'diff' command was ok, the 'grep' command didn't output anything and the `awk` command outputed errors. The files I'm using aren't just file1 file2 and have `/` and `.conf`

Comment: The command I ran was `awk 'NR == FNR {files\/icinga2-01-lab\.conf[$0]++; next} !($0 in files\/icinga2-01-lab\.conf)' files/icinga2-01-lab.conf files/compare/icinga2-01-lab.conf`

Comment: What is the 3rd file? You mentioned only 2 in the question.

Comment: Don't change the internal names in awk, it is meant to be an array and not the same name as the files processed. Refer my update in awk. Just change the files and NOT the internal variable names.

Comment: I ran `awk 'NR == FNR {file1[$0]++; next} !($0 in file1)' files/icinga2-01-lab.conf files/compare/icinga2-01-lab.conf` and there's no output, but I know I have two more records in files/compare/icinga2-01-lab.conf than files/icinga2-01-lab.conf

Comment: The order is important, specify 2nd the file which is expected to have the difference among the two files. Both the awk and grep solutions are dependent on the order of files. Did it work for you?