# Difference between 2 files block not line

Tags: bash

I have found something similar [What's the best way to diff blocks of text between two files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748310/whats-the-best-way-to-diff-blocks-of-text-between-two-files) however it doens't work for me.

so I have 2 files

file1

```
block1
 sometext

block2
 sometext
 sometext2
 changedtext3

newblock3
 newtext
```

file2

```
block1
 sometext

block2
 sometext
 sometext2
```

When I use `diff file1 file2`
I get a result

```
changedtext2
newblock3
 newtext
```

which is correct.
However is there a way to get a block where the change was made not just a line that was added/changed?

so I would like to get result like this

```
block2
 sometext
 sometext2
 changedtext3
newblock3
 newtext
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use `diff -c file1 file2` , but you'll need some output formatting to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting the lines in the block together into one line using
some delimiter, performing `diff`, then breaking the lines back again:

```
diff <(awk -v RS="" '{gsub("\n", "\033")} 1' file1) \
     <(awk -v RS="" '{gsub("\n", "\033")} 1' file2) \
     | tr "\033" "\n"
```

Output:

```
2,3c2
< block2
 sometext
 sometext2
 changedtext3
< newblock3
 newtext
---
> block2
 sometext
 sometext2
```

- The option `-v RS=""` tells `awk` to split the file on empty lines,
  meaning each record corresponds to each block.
- `gsub("\n", "\033")` substitutes the newline characters in the record with escape
  characters assuming the character is not used in the file.
- The `1` next to the right curly bracket is equivalent to "print the record".
- Then the `diff` command compares the files block by block.
- Finally `tr "\033" "\n"` retrieves the newline characters in the block.

The output is not identical to your desired output, but will be close.

**[Update]**
If there may be no empty line between the blocks, please try:

```
diff <(sed $'s/^[^[:blank:]]/\\n&/' file1 | awk -v RS="" '{gsub("\n", "\033")} 1') \
     <(sed $'s/^[^[:blank:]]/\\n&/' file2 | awk -v RS="" '{gsub("\n", "\033")} 1') \
     | tr "\033" "\n"
```

It prepends a newline character to the starting string of the block
as a preprocessing. It works with or without the empty lines.

Comment: thank you for that, it does work, but what if there are no empty line what if they are joined. Because its not always separated

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer accordingly. Would you please try it?